# Is it possible to plumb an appliance with a reservoir directly to a filtered water supply?

Tags: plumbing, water, appliances, water-pressure

I have a [Ninja CP307 coffee maker](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FX73Y7H). It's great, but I hate having to fill it up with filtered water every day. It sits next to my fridge which I plumbed up to my [reverse osmosis water system](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0844HF76N). I assume there is some kind of tubing that takes the water from the filter to a pump. If I plumb the pump to a water line directly will that enable me to bypass the water reservoir on these kinds of appliances? Is there any danger in having a pump connect right to a pressured water line? Will I need a regulator?

Comment: Why you need to connect pump to pressured water line? Is it not enough pressure?

Comment: @user263983 because the water line that feeds into the Reverse Osmosis system is pressurized so the water coming out is also pressurized (but granted far less).

Answer (score -1):

Water flows to match its own level.  You could set a tank to fill based on a level switch (like that of a toilet).  Then, run a hose to the appliance.  The top of the tank will be the top of the fill line on the appliance.

Of course, stuff grows in water, so no telling what you'd find after a few months in the tank or appliance, especially as there is no chlorine or chloramine left in the RO water.